# How to start push to the secondary repository with Git

Tags: git

The first repository is on server_A, there is server B and C got it's clone, and commit/push a few to original server_A. Then, server_A down.  From server_C, How to push to server_B instead?

Git is designed for this kind of condition.  But I found many terms and options in "*git help remote*", they are branches, masters, heads, tags, urls, merge mirrors and mores.  A line of command for this condition would be helpful, thank you.

Comment: @wurfkeks and @larsmans are both right, and after server_A up again, `git pull server_B <my_branch>` make it up to date. By the way, `git fetch` not work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest to add a second remote url to the repository of server_C. Go into the folder that contains your repository on server_C. Then execute

```
git remote add server_b <url-to-repository-b>
```

and then you can push changes:

```
git push server_b [reference]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
git remote add serverB user@serverB:foo/bar.git
git push serverB <branch>
```